# What is really replaced by a substitution in a RewriteRule inside .htaccess files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to understand the Apache Rewrite Module. The documentation at [RewriteRule Directive Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) says:

> The Substitution of a rewrite rule is the string that replaces the original URL-path that was matched by Pattern.

Does it mean that the whole URL-Path is replaced when a match occurs or only the part that is matched by the regex?

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^test new
```

Now I type into my browser: `http://example.com/test/file.php`

`test/file.php` is matched against `^test` and the substitution is `new`. How will the result look like?

`new/file.php` or just `new`?

What exactly is replaced here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "new/file.php" or just "new"?

Just "new". The *substitution* string replaces the *whole* URL-path if the *Pattern* matched.

In order to get the result `new/file.php`, having requested `/test/file.php`, you would need a slightly different directive. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) new/$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE:** Note that the above is an *internal rewrite* (as opposed to an *external redirect*). The rewrite is internal to the server, the user does not see this.

Also note that `new/$1` is a *relative* path (as opposed to root-relative - starting with a slash, or absolute - with a scheme + hostname).

If the `.htaccess` file is in the root directory then you shouldn't need to include the slash prefix (for an *internal rewrite*) since - by default - it's relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file. (No harm to add it though.) The *directory-prefix* (the absolute filesystem path of where the `.htaccess` file is located) is added back to relative path substitutions at the end. So `new/file.php` actually becomes `/path/to/root-directory/new/file.php` (when the `.htaccess` file is located at `/path/to/root-directory/.htaccess`).

However, if you were creating an *external redirect* then you would need a slash prefix (in order to make it root-relative - relative to the document root), or set the `RewriteBase` directive (which overrides the *directory-prefix*). Otherwise, you would end up with an external redirect to `http://example.com/path/to/root-directory/new/file.php` - which is most probably "wrong".

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) /new/$1 [R,L]
```

Note the `R` flag, that triggers an *external redirect* back to the client.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it clear to me. I tried something similar to your example. I figured out that I always need to add a slash to the substitution like `/new/$1` in order to get the expected result. Do you know why? Since the .htaccess file is in the root folder and the relative path should work?

Comment: "add a slash to the substitution like `/new/$1` in order to get the expected result." - what was happening otherwise? I've updated my answer to try and explain some things.

Comment: Thank you for this very well written answer, now I understood how it works. And that confuses me at the same time. My problem described above: When I do not put the slash in front of the substitution, I expect that `/test/file.php` will be rewritten to ´/new/file.php` since my .htaccess file is located at the root path. But I get a 404 result meaning the rewrite did not work. I am using shared hosting and I can choose the root directory via a website. Maybe this directory is not the _real_ root folder? I am just curious why this happens, since adding the slash is no problem at all.

Comment: I made a few tests now, I hope this is still in the scope of this question here: I could extract the rewritten url with a second rewrite rule just after the first one. Without the slash in front, the file will be rewritten internal to `path/to/root-directory/new/file.php`. What is missing here is the first slash that indicates an absolute path from the root folder. I created this path `/path/to/root-directory/path/to/root-directory/new/file.php` (double root path) and I could get my file with a 200 status code. I think this means there is some misconfiguration?

Comment: That means it is making a kind of an external redirect without any specified flags and without a redirect in my browser?!

Comment: "And that confuses me at the same time." - mod_rewrite is powerful and that naturally results in a certain amount of complexity. That being said, mod_rewrite does have its quirks! "But I get a 404" - Yes, that is unexpected. It should work. It implies there is "something else" going on! If you have nothing else in your config file then it could be something that your _shared host is doing_. "adding the slash is no problem at all" - yes, just add the slash. Alternatively you can set `RewriteBase /` once at the top of the script.

Comment: However, using relative substitutions can be useful when the `.htaccess` file is in a subdirectory or you need to inherit directives from parent configs. "I could extract the rewritten url with a second rewrite rule just after the first one" - if you could add these directives to your question, I'd be interested to have a look. Thanks.